# passing data to $modal in AngularUI

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

Folks,

I am using Angular ui $modal to create modals.
When I try to pass data to the modal  using resolve I am getting various errors. Could someone point me in the right direction ?

```
  // Manage Views
  $scope.openProductListModal = function() {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'products/manageProductList.tpl.html',
      controller: 'ManageProductListCtrl',
      resolve: {
        userpref: function() {return $scope.user.prefrences;};
        cartSelection: function() {return return $scope.user.cart;};
        prevSelects:function() {return $scope.prev.selects;}
      }
    });

  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax errors in your code.

- Replace the last `;` char in the first 2 lines of resolve with a `,`
- Remove the double `return` statement in `cartSelection`

Like this:

```
// Manage Views
$scope.openProductListModal = function() {
  var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'products/manageProductList.tpl.html',
    controller: 'ManageProductListCtrl',
    resolve: {
      userpref: function() {return $scope.user.prefrences;},
      cartSelection: function() {return $scope.user.cart;},
      prevSelects:function() {return $scope.prev.selects;}
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: gustavohenke,I have tried that approach and it does not work. I get the following error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : "

Comment: Sorry, I've double checked the code. There was another error; take a look again.